# Vagrant box does not see new box_url even after reloading

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I updated my Vagrantfile's confg.vm.box_url to a new URL (the box is hosted on a server who's IP changed) and no amount of vagrant reloading will make Vagrant see the new URL. When I run `vagrant reload --debug`, I see it attempt to fetch metadata from the old URL.

The relevant debug output:

```
==> default: Checking if box 'tute_development' is up to date...
 INFO downloader: Downloader starting download: 
 INFO downloader:   -- Source: http://10.0.1.36/vagrant/tute_development/tute_development.json
```

Here's the relevant part of the vagrant file:

```
config.vm.box_url = "http://192.168.1.104/vagrant/tute_development/tute_development.json"
```

How do I make the vagrant box see the new box_url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately the intended behavior of Vagrant. To quote this Github issue (https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4235):

> The box URL in the config is only meant to be used if the box doesn't
>   exist (by its logical name) in the local box registry (vagrant box
>   list). To force a new box to be downloaded you'd have to update the
>   name, or point the URL to a metadata JSON with a higher version.

The metadata JSON being referred to is the JSON file that the `config.vm.box_url` property points to. In my case, it was pointing to an internal network IP address that had changed, so I edited the metadata_url file in `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/{boxname}/metadata_url`.

Comment: Changing the URL in this file helped to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way I would suggest is deleting the default base Vagrant downloaded the first time (on Windows at something like : `C:\Users\[Username]\.vagrant.d\boxes\[YourBoxName]`). When reloading, Vagrant will look for it, won't find it, and download it again, using the URL you changed.

Hope this helps.